# Activate CSS animation by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html, animation

I got a red square (DIV) and everytime I click on it I like it to fade in and out using CSS animation.

```
<div id="BLOCK" style="background-color:red;width:150px;height:150px;">RED SQUARE</div>

<script>$('#BLOCK').click( function() {} );</script>
```

When I hang the animation to a class such a fade it works:

```
<script>$('#BLOCK').click( function() { $('#BLOCK').addClass('fade'); } );</script>
```

But once I click again, nothing happened, which is pretty logic because the class is already added. But this does not work.

```
<script>$('#BLOCK').click( function() { $('#BLOCK').removeClass('fade'); $('#BLOCK').addClass('fade'); } );</script>
```

So does anyone know of a better way?

Comment: What does your CSS animation look like (code wise)?

Comment: if you add the css transitions on both classes, it should work back & forth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

made a quick example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uc8vn/

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(ev){
       $('div').toggleClass('fade'); 
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});​

div{
    transition:opacity .3s linear;   
    -moz-transition:opacity .3s linear;   
    -webkit-transition:opacity .3s linear;   
    opacity:1;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
div.fade{
    opacity:0;   
}
​
```

Answer (score 4):

here a quick example on animation with add and remove class.

http://jsfiddle.net/q8ew0a5b/6/

```js
$( "#stop" ).click(function() {
  $( "#animated" ).addClass( "off" );
});
$( "#start" ).click(function() {
  $( "#animated" ).removeClass( "off" );
});
```

```css
@keyframes grow {
 0% {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 }
 
 100% {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
 }
}

#animated {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: silver;
 margin: 1em 0;
 animation: grow 1s infinite;
}

#animated.off {
 animation-name: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
</p>
<div id="animated"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pause and play animations using the animation-play-state property. 
I used the global variable to prevent the animation from bubbling.

See this quick demo fiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/d5mym5e7/6/

```
var running = 0;
$('#fade').on('click',function(){
    if (running === 0){
        running = 1;
        $('.box').css({
            '-webkit-animation-play-state':'running'
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.box').css({
                '-webkit-animation-play-state':'paused'
            });
            running = 0;
            console.log(running);
        },4000);
    } else {
        console.log('let me finish');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already are using jQuery, why don't you do the fadin animation with jQuery?

```
$('#BLOCK').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(function () { // Callback for chaining
        $(this).fadeOut();
    );
});
```

Comment: The fading was just an example of a more complex animation, but I am not using jQuery's animation as most of the older iOS devices have trouble executing them it doesn't go as smooth as CSS animations (check for yourself).